# call PHP function from Javascript with POST

Tags: javascript, php

I started working on a website written in PHP and I am not able to figure this one out!

I have a javascript function that looks like this:

```
    $(".buildbutton").click(function() {
        var locId = localStorage.getItem("locationID");
        var buildingId = $(this).attr('id');
        $.post("?bPage=townFunctions", {
            location: locId,
            buildingId: buildingId
        }).done(function () {
            window.location.href = "?page=dorp";
           
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am trying to call a function in townFunctions.php which is accessed by 'bPage'
From there:

```
if (isset($_POST['location'])) {
    
    createBuilding($_POST['location'], $_POST['buildingId']);
}
```

I am checking for the POST variable, but it doesn't seem to register... Any tips or hints how to check where the error is?

I checked in the DevTool if the function is called and it does.
If I call the function directly in PHP it works fine.

[image: DevTool]
[image: Devtool]

futhermore:

This are the access logs.

```
::1 - - [10/Aug/2021:01:07:54 +0200] "GET /?page=builder HTTP/1.1" 200 11085
//Here is the click on ".buildbutton"
::1 - - [10/Aug/2021:01:07:55 +0200] "POST /?bPage=townFunctions HTTP/1.1" 200 4801
::1 - - [10/Aug/2021:01:07:55 +0200] "GET /?page=dorp HTTP/1.1" 200 3439
```

When I call the PHP function directly, in
`?page=dorp`
the function works and doenst give any errors..

I checked with a var_dump($POST) on
`?bPage=townFunctions`
And that array is empty...

-Zeeebass

Comment: It should be `$.post("townFunctions.php", ...)`

Comment: `       } elseif ($_GET['bPage'] === "townFunctions") {
            include("..\backend\townFunctions.php");
`
I am running this code in my pager.php so its getting included somewehre else

Comment: In that case I can't see any reason why it doesn't work, unless there's some earlier code that clears `$_POST`.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST);` show in `townFunctions.php`?

Comment: var_dump($_POST); is empty...

Comment: The only thing that is using POST is the register and login form

Comment: Are you sure there are no redirects taking place? A redirect will switch from POST to GET.

Comment: I checked again, and i dont see anything that would redirect it...
That's the only javascript

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235806/discussion-between-barmar-and-zeeebass).